# D3 - Select by id

Tags: javascript, json, csv, d3.js

data.json has an id field for each entry. This id maps directly to an id in test.csv. I'm creating circles for every object in data.json. I'd like to then read test.csv and alter the attributes of only the circles with ids that appear in test.csv. I think I'm probably missing something fundamental here...

My most recent attempt to do this is a nested select. I first select all circles, then select only the circles with the ids in question.  Here's the code to create the circles, then edit them.

```
        d3.json("data.json", function(error, data){
            svg.selectAll("circle")
                .data(data)
                .enter()
                .append("circle")
                .attr("stroke", "black")
                .attr("fill", "white")
                .attr("r", 4)
                .attr("cx", function(d){ return d.x; })
                .attr("cy", function(d){ return d.y; })
                .attr("id", function(d){return "i:" + d.id;})
                .append("svg:title")
                .text(function(d){ return d.id; });
        });

        d3.csv("test.csv", function(csv){
            csv.sort(function(a,b){
                return new Date(b.timestamp+"Z") < new Date(a.timestamp+"Z") ? 1 : -1;
            });

            svg.selectAll("circle")
                .data(csv)
                .selectAll( function(d) { return "#i:" + d.roomId; } )
                .data(function(d) { return d; } )
                .transition()
                .duration(500)
                .attr("fill", "red");
        });
```

To sum up the results, nothing happens.  The initial circles are created, but the transitions never occur.  Some print statements suggest that I'm successfully nabbing the circles with the ids from test.csv, but I'm not even sure of that...  Any suggestions on how to improve this code?  Even if this model can be fixed, I have a feeling there's a much cleaner solution anyway.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the second part, you would need a loop like this, not a nested selection:

```
csv.forEach(function(d) {
  svg.select("#i:" + d.roomId)
  .transition()
  .duration(500)
  .attr("fill", "red");
})
```

The alternative would be to load both files and do what you want to do based on the contents of the CSV at the same time as appending the circles:

```
d3.json(url, function(error, data) {
  d3.csv(url, function(error, csv) {
    // preprocess CSV
    svg.selectAll("circle").data(data).enter().append("circle")
       // set attributes
       // filter selection to contain only those elements that appear in the CSV as well
       .filter(function(d) {
         return csv.filter(function(e) { return e.roomId == d.id; }).length > 0;
       })
       .transition()
       .duration(500)
       .attr("fill", "red");
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice, @Lars.  Unfortunately, the svg.select statement is throwing an error in your first suggestion.

"SyntaxError: An invalid or illegal string was specified"

I can't figure out why...  Any other suggestions?

Comment: What is `d.roomId`? It sounds like the string isn't a valid ID.

Comment: Just a string.  The circle with that id definitely exists.  The string starts with a number, but I added the "i:" prefix to combat any issues that might generate...

Comment: Hmm, could you post a complete example where this occurs please?

Comment: I took the colon out of the id name, and that fixed the problem. Now we know. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Oh yes, of course. Colons are allowed in IDs, but funnily enough not in selectors...